# Image deployment with config files

Tags: docker

I have an image what i want deploy. Imagine web app in `myapp:latest` image:

```
FROM debian:jessie
[...]
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/bin/run_myapp.sh"]
```

Where **/bin/run_myapp.sh** load a config file from **/etc/myapp.conf**.
To deploy 3 instances with 3 differents config files i think to do something like:

```
C1=$(docker run -d myapp)
C2=$(docker run -d myapp)
C3=$(docker run -d myapp) 
...

docker cp myapp1.conf $C1:/etc/myapp.conf
docker cp myapp2.conf $C2:/etc/myapp.conf
docker cp myapp3.conf $C3:/etc/myapp.conf
```

But with that idea, containers are already running, so **/bin/run_myapp.sh** already read **/etc/myapp.conf**. If i `docker cp` before launch myapp, containers does not exists.

What `docker` solution can be used to this deployment scenario ?

Comment: I usually use environment variables by --env or --env-file. This way there's not code/script change between dev and prod. If you must use config file, maybe you can build all three of them into the image and use --env to specify its location during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `create` in thirst step, then do the `cp` and finally `start` containers.

```
C1=$(docker create myapp)
C2=$(docker create myapp)
C3=$(docker create myapp) 

docker cp myapp1.conf $C1:/etc/myapp.conf
docker cp myapp2.conf $C2:/etc/myapp.conf
docker cp myapp3.conf $C3:/etc/myapp.conf 

docker start $C1
docker start $C2
docker start $C3
```